# When does a private fast begin?

Tags: halacha, fast-days

When does a private fast (תענית יחיד) begin? At sunset or at dawn? Is it considered a fast like Yom Kippur (24 hr.) or like a half-day fast?

Are there any sources that address this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R Jack Abramowitz from the OU brings sources [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/881-committing-advance-fast/) and [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/883-end-personal-fast/) that it goes from **dawn to the time three stars come out.**

> If an individual wants to take a fast upon himself, he must commit to do so the day before at mincha. [...] **It makes no difference that
>   he will continue to eat and drink after this until dawn.**
>
> On a private fast, **one may rinse his mouth with water in the
>   morning.**
>
> If one accepted upon himself to fast without any conditions, then he must do so **until three stars come out at night**

See also [here](https://torah.org/learning/shulchan-aruch-classes-orachchayim-chapter40/).

Note there are other opinions on the timing of the end of the fast (see [Orach Chaim 562](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.562.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), so as always, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

Comment: There might be other opinions for start times too